# Error importing database to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've created a backup of my local database through "Export Data Tier Application" and I saved the file at Azure Blob.

At Azure Portal, I choose my SQL Server and import a new database. I select the backup from the Blob, and wait a long time for the DB creation. It stucks at 1% all the time.

After 40 minutes, I get this message every single time I try to create the database:

> The ImportExport operation with Request Id
> 'f6743e06-592d-4531-b319-4297b345f744e' failed due to 'Could not
> import package. Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server
> 2019 or Azure SQL Database Managed Instance as the target platform may
> experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
> Warning SQL72012: The object [data_0] exists in the target, but it
> will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop
> statements for objects that are in the target database but that are
> not in the source' check box. Warning SQL72012: The object [log]
> exists in the target, but '.

This is very frustrating, its just a database with tables (with no data) that only weights 25 megs. Im following every single tutorial to make this work, every single step, and I always get that error, no matter which database name I choose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going through the process of creating a bacpac, upload it to an Azure Storage account and the fail at the end to import it to Azure SQL, you can easily migrate that SQL Server to azure using [Azure Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateonpremsqltosqldb?view=sql-server-ver15) (DMA).

You just have to create an empty Azure SQL Database, and DMA do the rest. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).

Comment: I will give it a try right now Alberto! It required me to download .NET framework 4.8 first... so I will let you know once its done. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. That tool is a gem.

Comment: Not really an answer to the problem, even if marked. There is a very specific function in Azure for IMPORTING DATABASES. Answer like yours is not only not helping, but is actually distracting from the topic. I have another problem using this functionality and ended up here, hoping for some clues but all I found was, in essence "Microsoft, meh".

Comment: Lots of appreciation! Works perfectly!